Why can't I receive Korean input using std::cin?
I am very confused now.
The execution environment is vscode, and the compiler is g++ installed with mingw64.
Below is the program I created:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void printString(const std::string &str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "hex: ";
    for (char ch : str)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "length: " << str.length() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string output = "안녕하세요!";
    printString(output);

    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    if (std::cin.fail() != 0) {
        return std::cin.fail();
    }
    printString(input);

    return 0;
}

The problem is that even though I typed "안녕하세요!" on the command line, the resulting output is strange:
안녕하세요!
hex: ec 95 88 eb 85 95 ed 95 98 ec 84 b8 ec 9a 94 21
length: 10
안녕하세요!
�����!
hex: 90 90 90 90 90 21
length: 6

Why am I getting strange results?
I don't know why it's the same string, but the results are different when entered as code and when entered as cin. It's a bit strange that the input strings have different lengths, but I couldn't figure out why.
The results I expect are below:
안녕하세요!
hex: ec 95 88 eb 85 95 ed 95 98 ec 84 b8 ec 9a 94 21
length: 10
안녕하세요!
안녕하세요!
hex: ec 95 88 eb 85 95 ed 95 98 ec 84 b8 ec 9a 94 21
length: 10

I also set the command window to handle UTF8 through chcp 65001.
